# How to select all comments in a Ruby file with a Regular Expression in the Atom text editor?

Tags: regex, ruby

What is a regular expression that can be used in the Atom text editor to select only the comments?

```
puts "Hello, world!"
# The puts command displays the character string in the output screen.
puts "Goodbye, world!
```

Comment: You can use `^#.*` which will only select lines that start with `#` and `.*` will select remaining characters in your line. Also, what language you are using?

Comment: `/^#.+$/gm` (m is a flag for multiline)

Comment: You have not mentioned what programming language you are using. `^#.+$` is the regex, and then you need to set the m flag for multline. And if you want to find more than one you need to set the g flag for global.

Comment: @thezeroandone: Sure it is easy. You can use this regex `^\h*#.*` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6EshBS/1/) And make sure to enable multiline mode by appending `(?m)` before the regex or enable the flag. Here `\h*` will optionally match all horizontal whitespaces (tabs and spaces) before `#`

Comment: If you want to allow white space before #: `^\s*#.+$`

Comment: Where are you using this? (are you using it inside an editor, and if so what editor?)

Comment: @thezeroandone: Don't use `\s*` before `#` else it will also match newline. Instead either use `\h*` if supported else use `[ \t]*` instead of `\s*`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi You are right, \s* was a bad choice. `^[ \t]*#.+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want `^[ \t]*#.+$`

```
^        Start of string
[ \t]*   Any number of space or tabs
#        The # character
.+       At least one more character
$        end of line
```

Comment: `\h` is not supported by all flavors of regex. It means *horizontal whitespace*